# Sound plays for half a second then stops?

Tags: audio, netlogo

When I play the sound file by itself (in interface) it works fine and plays all the way through. However, when I play it as part of the code (followed by an action) it only plays the first half second. I'm using sound:play-sound-and-wait, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```
extensions [sound] ; I have them in the same folder

to-report mouse-up?
  ifelse mouse-down?
    [report "false"]
    [report "true"]
end

to twirl
  if mouse-up?
    [ask turtles with [shape = ballerina] 
      [set shape ballerina-2
       twirl]
    ask turtles with [shape = ballerina-2]
      [set shape ballerina
       twirl]  ]
end
```

These are 2 different ballerina's facing different directions. When you switch between them, they look like they're twirling. She keeps doing that until you make her stop

```
to ballet-box
  ask patches [set plabel-color 105] ;gives the background this color

  sound:play-sound-and-wait "love.aif" ;this works perfectly fine in interface

 twirl ;and then I want the ballerina to twirl until you make her stop
end
```

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate how you are playing the audio

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like http://github.com/NetLogo/Sound-Extension/issues/2 or http://github.com/NetLogo/Sound-Extension/issues/3 . I don't think anyone has yet investigated or attempted to fix these issues. I don't think we even know under exactly what circumstances they do or don't occur.